# Facebook Like Custom Profile URL PHP

Tags: php, facebook, profile

Making a website and I want to put in a custom profile URL for all the users on my site (like facebook).

On my website already, people have a page like http://sitename.com/profile.php?id=100224232

However, I want to make a mirror for those pages that relates to their username. For example, if you go to http://sitename.com/profile.php?id=100224232 it redirects to you http://sitename.com/myprofile

How would I go about doing this with PHP and Apache?

Answer (score 8):

No folders, no index.php

Just take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.phpaddiction.com/tags/axial/url-routing-with-php-part-one/).

**Edit :**
This is just a summary.

### 0) Context

I'll assume that we want the following URLs :

> http://example.com/profile/userid (get a profile by the ID) 
>   http://example.com/profile/username (get a profile by the username) 
>   http://example.com/myprofile (get the profile of the currently logged-in user)

### 1) .htaccess

Create a .htaccess file in the root folder or update the existing one :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

*What does that do ?*

If the request is for a real directory or file (one that exists on the server), index.php isn't served, else every url is redirected to **index.php**.

### 2) index.php

Now, we want to know what action to trigger, so we need to read the URL :

In index.php :

```php
// index.php    

// This is necessary when index.php is not in the root folder, but in some subfolder...
// We compare $requestURL and $scriptName to remove the inappropriate values
$requestURI = explode(‘/’, $_SERVER[‘REQUEST_URI’]);
$scriptName = explode(‘/’,$_SERVER[‘SCRIPT_NAME’]);

for ($i= 0; $i < sizeof($scriptName); $i++)
{
    if ($requestURI[$i] == $scriptName[$i])
    {
        unset($requestURI[$i]);
    }
}

$command = array_values($requestURI);
```

With the url http://example.com/profile/19837, $command would contain :

```
$command = array(
    [0] => 'profile',
    [1] => 19837,
    [2] => ,
)
```

Now, we have to dispatch the URLs. We add this in the index.php :

```php
// index.php

require_once("profile.php"); // We need this file
switch($command[0])
{
    case ‘profile’ :
        // We run the profile function from the profile.php file.
        profile($command([1]);
        break;
    case ‘myprofile’ :
        // We run the myProfile function from the profile.php file.
        myProfile();
        break;
    default:
        // Wrong page ! You could also redirect to your custom 404 page.
        echo "404 Error : wrong page.";
        break;
}
```

### 2) profile.php

Now in the profile.php file, we should have something like this :

```php
// profile.php

function profile($chars)
{
    // We check if $chars is an Integer (ie. an ID) or a String (ie. a potential username)

    if (is_int($chars)) {
        $id = $chars;
        // Do the SQL to get the $user from his ID
        // ........
    } else {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($char);
        // Do the SQL to get the $user from his username
        // ...........
    }

    // Render your view with the $user variable
    // .........
}

function myProfile()
{
    // Get the currently logged-in user ID from the session :
    $id = ....

    // Run the above function :
    profile($id);
}
```

### To conclude

I wish I was clear enough. I know this code is not pretty, and not in an OOP style, but it could give some ideas...

Comment: Could you please explain more, I don't really get the route as I have very little experience with apache