# How can I create a dynamic url with your username?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to create a dynamic url such that when I log in from my website my username will be shown on the url. For example, say I log in with:

http://example-website.com

with my username myname. The url should become

http://example-website.com/myname

but actually the web page is loginsuccess.php with an alias of myname which is my username

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Like Custom Profile URL PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10595556/254830) as RakeshS mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy with `.htaccess` and [RewriteEngine](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs). In the example below I'll be using some really simple `(.*)` regex, which is just a wildcard so that everything will be accepted (`a-zA-z0-9`).

**`/username` *prefixed* with `profile`**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*) user_profile.php?username=$1
ErrorDocument 404 /pathtofile/404.html
```

Result: http://www.example-website.com/profile/john-smith

**Working with just `username`, this option will require some sort of [`Routing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115629/simplest-php-routing-framework) class.**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) user_profile.php?username=$1
ErrorDocument 404 /pathtofile/404.html
```

Result: http://www.example-website.com/john-smith

**Using RewriteEngine with *Suffix* `auth`**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/auth auth_user.php?username=$1&q=auth
ErrorDocument 404 /pathtofile/404.html
```

Result: http://www.example-website.com/john-smith/auth

Answer (score 1):

Quick Tips:

- Store unique username in a table.
- Enable rewrite module in your http-server ([here's a tutorial on that](http://www.phpaddiction.com/tags/axial/url-routing-with-php-part-one/)).
- Rewrite the URL http://example.com/username to a route.php (or something similar).
- Route.php should read the URL and extract the username and cross-verify it with the appropriate table.
- If a match is found then show the appropriate page otherwise 404.
- DONE!

For a thorough explanation, see [Facebook Like Custom Profile URL PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10595607/765854).