# URL Rewriting in PHP / Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

So I am making an website using php to show  users and there post for other site using API .

So I have URL likes **mysite.com/user.php?username=demo** . 
So is there any way I can make it **mysite.com/user/demo.**
I made searches here I came to know that Its call **URL_rewriting** . But as I am *newbie* to **php / apache** Can any one will help me in making my .htaccess

my site url now is > site.com/user.php?name=namehere.

any small help will be appreciated thanks .

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595556/facebook-like-custom-profile-url-php

Comment: simply the rule is 

`RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I learned from this](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

You can do

```
RewriteRule ^user/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  user.php?username=$1    [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks ! This worked . But I am having Error with my CSS Codes ?

Comment: try adding `<base href="http://domain.com">` inside `<head>` tag of your html file